# Visual Studio Server-Explorer Window

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am using VS 2008 WebDeveloper Express edition.
And i'm developing a little aplication, in which i would like to use Performance Counters.
So i went reading a couple of articles, and i found [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx).
However in the Figure 1, it shows a window that i don't have. I reseted all the the windows in the WebDeveloper, and i searched in the View and Window menu... but i didn't find that menu!

Does VS WebDeveloper 2008 Express edition even have that window?
And how can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the VS 2008 WebDeveloper Express edition does not have the Server explorer window, instead it has the database explorer window which is more limited that the Server explorer. This is an intentional limitation of the IDE.

Furthermore the IDE will only work with local data sources and read-only remote connections.

You have a few options, e.g.

1. Use SQL Express on your local machine
2. Purchase a copy of the Visual Studio 2008 which will remove this limitation
3. Manually code your database access, you don't get IDE support but it will work just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, for not understanding it quite well... but i still don't understand how SQL express will solve the problem of not being able to view this window.

Comment: SQL Express will count as a local datasource, so you should be able to see it using the Database explorer window